# AudioKit v5 - Why does the app crash in the simulator, but not on an actual device?

Tags: swift, crash, ios-simulator, audiokit

I have spent some time building a simple synth application. I have imported the following AudioKit packages into the app:

```
import AudioKit
import AudioKitEX
import DunneAudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit
```

The application builds and runs fine on my actual device, an iPhone 13 mini. However, when I test the app on the Xcode simulators, the app crashes before it is able to load any of the user interface.

I get the following message in the console:

```
2022-11-05 18:07:48.727337-0500 SYNTH-APP-BETA-1[65947:1665594] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000035ccda0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
(lldb)
```

Also, when the app crashes, the following part of the code is highlighted in a red line. Specifically, the line that begins `ft->lobits`. I believe this is `AudioKit` code:

```
/* initialize constants in ftable */
int sp_ftbl_init(sp_data *sp, sp_ftbl *ft, size_t size)
{
    ft->size = size;
    ft->sicvt = 1.0 * SP_FT_MAXLEN / sp->sr;
    ft->lobits = log2(SP_FT_MAXLEN / size);
    ft->lomask = (1<<ft->lobits) - 1;
    ft->lodiv = 1.0 / (1<<ft->lobits);
    ft->del = 1;
    return SP_OK;
}
```

Here is a screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Any help would be nice. Otherwise, I will probably restart the whole application and build on simulators much earlier in the process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this crash. I would start with the standard stuff: resetting Swift package caches, delete the app from the simulator, clean project, close and reopen Xcode. Also I'm not sure if you need to include `import AudioKitEX` on this level unless it throws some errors removing it.

Comment: Tried everything, but no luck. Thank you for the response, though!